# Getting different MongoDB instances per ip on local network

Tags: mongodb

I have two windows machine:

- Machine A with local ip 192.168.1.3
- Machine B with local ip 192.168.1.4

I have installed MongoDB server on machine A and set bind_ip to 0.0.0.0 so I can also access it from machine B.

When I connect to the DB from machine A using localhost, looks like I get different instance from when I connect to it from machine B using ip 192.168.1.3 (by different instance I mean I don't see the DBs and collections I have created from localhost on machine A, looks new)

I have also noticed that when I connect to DB using ip 192.168.1.3 from machine A, I also get the new instance instead of the one from the localhost connection

Anyone knows why this happens?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify you have a single `mongod` process running on .3 and no mongod processes running on .4.

If you have more than one running, shut down all but one and connect in all the ways you tried, you'll receive an error on the connection that is misconfigured.